# Windows 10: How to make new Personalisation settings active immediately, by PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, desktop

I may change the Personalisation settings of Windows 10, 
e.g. the background photo,

by changing the proper registry entry either manually with RegEdit or by a Powershell command "New-ItemPropery" with proper parameters.
My experience: The new Personalisation settings in the Registry - I can check that with RegEdit that all is properly changed - are just active after next Windows reboot or Windows user logout+login.
Btw, I am using the free tool "WhatChanged" to detect the Registry changes after simple changes in the Personalisation settings.
So I am able to change the background image, for the price of a Windows logout+login, currently.

However, If I do the same with the graphical configuration tool of Windows 10, executed by selecting "Personalise" after Mouse-rightclick, changes in the Personalisation settings are active immediately, i.e. the background picture changes immediately.

Question:

---

Is there a free tool or even better a PowerShell function (call) or any other free solution, by that I get changes of the Windows Personalisation ( and Windows Desktop ) settings activated, immediately?

---

I am using Windows10, but of course solutions which work for Win95,Win98, W2k, WInXP, WIn7 are welcomed too...

Reason:
For increasing the development speed, I would like to "see" immediately when I do changes to the registry, i.e. for the Windows Personalisation, but in general for third-party software too.

From my experience, for other third-party software it is quite normal, that registry changes will just become activated after a restart of the software, if the registry settings are just read once at start of program.  But I even then, I must not do a Windows logout + login for that...

Sincerely
Rolf

Answer (score 2):

To apply desktop changes, you need to call the Win32 API [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) from user32.dll.

Although you cannot call a native Win32 API directly from PowerShell, you can call it from C# via `System.Runtime.InteropServices`, and you can import C# assemblies into PowerShell.  The following PowerShell code creates a C# assembly to call `SystemParametersInfo`.

```
Add-Type @"
namespace Wallpaper {
    public class Setter {
        public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
        public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
        public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);

        public static void SetWallpaperFile ( string path ) {
            SystemParametersInfo( SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, path, UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange );
        }
    }
}
"@ 

function Set-Wallpaper {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Path)

    [Wallpaper.Setter]::SetWallpaperFile( $Path )
}
```

If you need to change the display style, update the appropriate registry keys before calling `SetWallpaperFile`.  For example, to set the wallpaper style to "Center":

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name 'WallpaperStyle' -Value '1'
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name 'TileWallpaper' -Value '0'
```

Changing settings other than the desktop wallpaper can be done similarly.  See the documentation for `SystemParametersInfo`.

*Code originally adapted from http://poshcode.org/491*